# Send commands to another C program

Tags: c, curl

There's an older program written in C that I have the source to and I want to send cURL. I noticed when trying to send/receive curl it has to wait for the response so the entire thread gets held up.

I was thinking of making another program to send/receive to keep the other program freed up. What's the easiest way of doing this? Is there a better way? My only restriction is it must be written in C.

Comment: Look at `fork` and `exec` family.

Comment: [`libcurl`'s "multi" interface can do async requests](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html)

Comment: This is a classic case of an A/B problem in a question, by the way --- you need to do A (async cURL requests), you *think* you need B (multiprocess operation), so you ask about B instead of A.

Comment: @TimČas It's [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Gabriel: Right, my bad. I've also heard it being used as the "AB problem". Point remains.

Comment: @TimČas Ended up using multi threading to solve the issue. For Windows I used CreateThread and Linux used pthread.

Comment: @user3459555: Yes, that's the usual way of doing it.